# 403 forbidden error when crawling a website using python requests on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, python-requests, web-crawler, http-status-code-403

I have written a crawler script that sends a post request to "sci-hub.do" and i've set it up running on Heroku . But when it tries to send a post or get request, i mostly get 403 forbidden message.

Strange thing is that this only happens when that script is running on Heroku cloud and when i run it on my PC it's all good and i get the 200 status code.

I have tried using a session but it did not work.
I also checked robots.txt of that website and set a User-Agent header to "Twitterbot/1.0" but it still failed.

What am i doing wrong? Why is it only happening when the script is running on Heroku.

I'm pretty sure that the webserver is detecting my script as a crawler bot and tries to block it. But why even after adding a proper "User-agent"?

Comment: This could be many factors, depending on the site in question. E.g,. things like Cloudflare might automatically block certain requests if they look suspicious (too rapid, acts like a bot, etc). I'm not familiar with sci-hub in particular, but perhaps they have some automatic bot-blocking in place that's clamping down on heroku servers/IPs, but not your home connection?

Comment: All that to say: User Agent is definitely *not* the only variable that might trigger automatic protection on a website. There are lots of possible variables.

Comment: This could be very possible. But as i mentioned in a comment below, i spontaneously get a 200 response, but after a few requests i'm blocked!

Comment: Any given web server is under no obligation to respond the same way all the time. I'm not surprised by that pattern. This is just a very hard question to definitively answer without much more intimate knowledge of the web server configuration itself. Very hard to know anything for sure from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a usual User Agent like:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36
```

Maybe you will need to use a random User-Agent for every request. Then you can install and use https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/

Comment: I did tried that. It some times works though, but after a couple of requests it changes to 403 again!

Comment: @Sherafati then I recommend you to install and try https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/ and generate for every request a random UA (updated main answer)

Comment: Surprisingly i did try it aswell. Still fails after a couple of requests.